# What is a possible way to store data from a stringstream into an unsigned long?

Tags: c++, sstream

I am trying to make a program which puts the contents stored in a stringstream (a large number) into an unsigned long format. But the compiler shows an error

> error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'std::stringstream {aka std::basic_stringstream}' to 'long unsigned int' [-fpermissive]|

The code I've written is:

```
stringstream raw_a;
stringstream raw_b;

//code which reads data into raw_a and raw_b

unsigned long out_a;
unsigned long out_b;

out_a = raw_a;
out_b = raw_b;
```

I have spent the last hour scouring the web in vain. Any help (including links to any other questions) is highly appreciated.

Comment: That's not how you use stringstreams... Did you look at the documentation at all?

Comment: @Borgleader: Im completely open to any help. Even a link to a page I should read.

Comment: An hour is not enough and the web is not enough. Spend a few days studying proper research material.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extract formatted data from a stringstream, do what you'd do with any other stream:

```
raw_a >> out_a;
```

Comment: @Vaibhav: Why do you feel the need to use that word?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Because, in retrospect this was a stupid question. I should have searched for the correct syntax on receiving that error. Unfortunately Stack is the only way I can clarify doubts, as I'm teaching myself.